# How add assembly on mv5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Im trying a project with mvc 5. But I cant see how I can add assembly here.

I need `System.Web.Mvc` for `JsonRequestBehavior`

I try on dependencies and using Nuget. But couldnt find it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuget package is called [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/)

You can install it from the package manager with the command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Comment: Ok, that work, but now Im getting ambiguos references with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` I want test the mvc 5 way. Maybe Im doing the wrong thing? dont want mix mvc version.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The nuget package for asp.net core mvc is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`. Depending on which framework you are using you should pick the appropriate nuget package (and only one of them).